# Switch to, and from, Preview, with 1 keyboard shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

I tried using `textInputFocus && !inputFocus && editorLangId == 'markdown'` and `textInputFocus && editorReadonly && editorLangId == 'markdown'` in When Expression for markdown.showSource, with relevant respective versions for markdown.showPreview .

But the shortcut still doesn't work when the Preview has Focus .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the `markdown.showSource` in the Keybindings Shortcuts you will see it has no context/when clause.  It must just find the matching resource and go to it.

Also when a preview is active, you will see that the `language ID` in the bottom right corner disappears, so `editorLangId == markdown` will presumably always fail.

If you want a `when` clause to prevent keybinding conflicts, try:

```
  {
    "key": "alt+e",
    "command": "markdown.showSource",
    "when": "markdownPreviewFocus"
  }
```

---

Learn about the `Developer: Inspect Context Keys` command, see [inspect context keys utility](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#inspect-context-keys-utility).  That is how I found the `markdownPreviewFocus` clause.

Comment: related -- `htmlPreviewFocus`